# 'Batik not in classpath' error when running servlet

Tags: java, servlets, classpath

I'm writing an extension of the FopServlet.java included in Apache FOP.

My platform is Linux CentOS 5.7-64bit, with Tomcat 5.5.

The `servlet` 'works', but I'm unable to process SVG files.

The error I get when Tomcat runs the `servlet` is

> 'Batik not in classpath'.

But in `'webapps/fop/WEB-INF/lib'` there is `'batik-all-1.7.jar'` and all the other jars.

I'm not a java expert, so I'm unable to focus on the problem; googling around, maybe there is a missing jar, but which one?

```
AVVERTENZA: Batik not in class path
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/svg/SVGDocument
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1862)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:888)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1341)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1220)
        at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGDOMImplementation.createDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.batik.dom.util.SAXDocumentFactory.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.batik.dom.util.SAXDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.batik.dom.util.SAXDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createSVGDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader.getImage(PreloaderSVG.java:122)
        at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader.access$100(PreloaderSVG.java:105)
        at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG.preloadImage(PreloaderSVG.java:73)
        at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageManager.preloadImage(ImageManager.java:175)
        at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.cache.ImageCache.needImageInfo(ImageCache.java:128)
        at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageManager.getImageInfo(ImageManager.java:122)
        at org.apache.fop.fo.flow.ExternalGraphic.bind(ExternalGraphic.java:81)
        at org.apache.fop.fo.FObj.processNode(FObj.java:123)
        at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:282)
        at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:171)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.startElement(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1072)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:484)
        at org.apache.fop.servlet.FopServlet.render(FopServlet.java:260)
        at org.apache.fop.servlet.FopServlet.renderFO(FopServlet.java:199)
        at org.apache.fop.servlet.FopServlet.doGet(FopServlet.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.svg.SVGDocument
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1374)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1220)
        ... 64 more
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It appears to be a [bug in Fop](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fop/+bug/268930) where they forgot to include a dependency.

The missing class is in the JAR file - `xml-apis-ext.jar` Which is also available from the [Apache xml-commons project](http://xml.apache.org/commons/index.html).

Comment: You just save me from this legacy app here. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

The error message is misleading, this is really a lack of xml commons external.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing Batik from fedora using the .jar file it is quite painful due to the java ignoring the -classpath flag.
I assume batik in /usr/share/java
Select the location according to your system
One solution could be the following:
create a scratch directory (I assume you are superuser, anyway you always can sudo commands)

```
# mkdir scratch
# cd scratch
# jar -xf /usr/share/java/batik-rasterizer.jar
```

This output the content of the jar file into scratch, then create a MANIFEST.MF file or take the output one from the dump

```
#cp META-INF/MANIFEST.MF .
```

Now edit the MANIFEST.MF file (I like to use vi, anyone use their preferred one)

```
#vi MANIFEST.MF
```

Add a Class-Path: line into the MANIFEST.MF as for example:

```
Class-Path: batik-all.jar xmlgraphics-commons.jar xml-commons-apis-ext.jar pdf-transcoder.jar avalon-framework.jar avalon-framework-api.jar apache-commons-logging.jar apache-commons-io.jar
```

Then close the file and recreate the jar file

```
#jar cmf MANIFEST.MF /usr/share/java/batik-rasterizer.jar org/*
```

Include all jar that batik has nested classes

Then you can use it!

```
$java -jar /usr/share/java/batik-rasterizer.jar -scriptSecurittyOff -m image/png -d image.png image.svg
```

for example

And that is!!!