# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while reading a svg file as BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, svg, java-2d, batik

i have a .svg file to create a Map which will have Listeners relevant to boundaries (i guess its called "nodes" of a scalable vector graphic). However, i'm trying to add this file as a BufferedImage over a JPanel. (i'm a newbie about swing components so if you have any better ideas please share ). Moreover, i used [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) library and read some information about it and i used this code sample to get this .svg file as BufferedImage

```
package org.pulpcore.tools.res;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGDOMImplementation;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscodingHints;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder;
import org.apache.batik.util.SVGConstants;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class SVGRasterizer {

    /**
     Rasterizes an SVG file using Batik.

     @param svgFile The svg file.
     @return The rasterized image.
     @throws IOException if the svg file could not be rasterized.
     */
    public static BufferedImage rasterize(File svgFile) throws IOException {

        final BufferedImage[] imagePointer = new BufferedImage[1];

        // Rendering hints can't be set programatically, so
        // we override defaults with a temporary stylesheet.
        // These defaults emphasize quality and precision, and
        // are more similar to the defaults of other SVG viewers.
        // SVG documents can still override these defaults.
        String css = "svg {" +
                "shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;" +
                "text-rendering:  geometricPrecision;" +
                "color-rendering: optimizeQuality;" +
                "image-rendering: optimizeQuality;" +
                "}";
        File cssFile = File.createTempFile("batik-default-override-", ".css");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(cssFile, css);

        TranscodingHints transcoderHints = new TranscodingHints();
        transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_XML_PARSER_VALIDATING, Boolean.FALSE);
        transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOM_IMPLEMENTATION,
                SVGDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation());
        transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT_NAMESPACE_URI,
                SVGConstants.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI);
        transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT, "svg");
        transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_USER_STYLESHEET_URI, cssFile.toURI().toString());

        try {

            TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(new FileInputStream(svgFile));

            ImageTranscoder t = new ImageTranscoder() {

                @Override
                public BufferedImage createImage(int w, int h) {
                    return new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                }

                @Override
                public void writeImage(BufferedImage image, TranscoderOutput out)
                        throws TranscoderException {
                    imagePointer[0] = image;
                }
            };
            t.setTranscodingHints(transcoderHints);
            t.transcode(input, null);
        }
        catch (TranscoderException ex) {
            // Requires Java 6
            //throw new IOException("Couldn't convert " + svgFile, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new IOException("Couldn't convert " + svgFile);
        }
        finally {
            cssFile.delete();
        }

        return imagePointer[0];
    }
}
```

this is my class to use GUI components and the part where i try to use BufferedImage

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class JRisk {

    private JFrame mainMap;

    public JRisk() throws IOException{

        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() throws IOException{

        mainMap = new JFrame();
        mainMap.setResizable(false);

                JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

                File riskMap = new File("src\\src\\risk.svg");

                BufferedImage bufImage = SVGRasterizer.rasterize(riskMap);

                mainMap.setIconImage(bufImage);

        mainMap.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                mainMap.add(mainPanel);
                mainMap.pack();
                mainMap.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

and finally, Test program which contains main method.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param argsh
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                        try {
                            new JRisk();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Well my problem is compiler gives an error which is

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/svg/SVGDocument
```

and the whole error is

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGDOMImplementation.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.dom.util.SAXDocumentFactory.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3063)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:881)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.apache.batik.dom.util.SAXDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.dom.util.SAXDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at src.SVGRasterizer.rasterize(SVGRasterizer.java:74)
    at src.JRisk.initComponents(JRisk.java:31)
    at src.JRisk.<init>(JRisk.java:17)
    at src.Test$1.run(Test.java:24)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.svg.SVGDocument
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 51 more
```

i will be very very appreciated if you can help about this topic even with useful suggesstions! And thanks anyway

Comment: How are you running your program, via IDE or commandline? What does your classpath look like?

Comment: i run it from Netbeans and i loaded the .jar files into project

Comment: Have you viewed this post? Maybe you can download the jar you need and add it to your project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891250/batik-not-in-classpath

Comment: yeah its finally ok thanks a lot!!! if you can write your comment as an answer i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following post my address your issue:
[Batik not in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891250/batik-not-in-classpath)

It seems as if the jar file may not be included in the Batik download, you can just download the needed jar library and add it to your project.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding **xml-apis.jar** and/or **xml-apis-ext.jar**. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case more than one jar file needed in order for batik to render SVG files to BufferedImage. Errors: several  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. Not sure if all needed, what exactly is missing or if there are overlaps but worth to try those:

```
w3c-css
w3c-dom
org.w3c.dom.smil
org.w3c.css.sac     
org.w3c.dom.svg
W3C SVG DOM Bindings For Java (aXSL Build)
svg-dom-java
apatche xmlgraphics-commons
```