# Working with SVG FILES in iReport gives JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : Source Text

Tags: java, svg, jasper-reports, ireport, batik

I've been working in an web project where the client needs to show a report like an Id card. I designed the structure of the report in Illustrator and exported as SVG, so BatikRenderer handles the file and shows it in the report. And in *iReport* just include the fields I'm going to show. So basically it works in *iReport Designer 5.5.0*.

When I Compile it and shows the preview. It seems like everything is ok.

[image]

Here is my jrxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="prueba" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" language="groovy" pageWidth="180" pageHeight="288" columnWidth="180" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="2cedbacf-8972-4cbe-bf07-7d3af62126d5">
<detail>
    <band height="288" splitType="Stretch">
        <image>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="288" uuid="3c8031c1-70ca-4e47-be8e-735b90b7797a"/>
<imageExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable"><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstanceFromLocation("svg-design.svg")]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

I used the other variation with the absolute path and it works too :

```
<![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstance(new java.io.File("/Users/RogelioMonge/Dropbox/Adepafut/src/java/com/adepafut/common/reports/svg-design.svg"))]]>
```

The problem is when I try to execute the report from my app. Im using my report with an Empty Data Source, just for the SVG test, I need to achieve this first so I can continue with the filling of the report with the DataSource.

Here is the dummy code I used to test the report:

```
try {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    JRDataSource dataSource = null;
    InputStream report = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(JugadorReportEnum.PATH_REPORT.getValue());
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, dataSource);
    JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
    jv.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
} catch (JRException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ReportHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Here is the Exception:

```
ex = (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException)net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstanceFromLocation("svg-design.svg")
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I forgot to include the batik libraries in my project. In my case that Im using a MAC OS. I searched the Batik libraries in the Ireport Designer.app/Contents/Resources/ireport/ireport/modules/ext/ folder. So you don't need to downloaded. This way is better so you ensure you are using the same jars your Ireport Designer is using. By the way you'll need the xml-apis-ext.jar, Its a dependency for the batik jars. This one can be found in the same folder of the Ireport Designer. Add all this jars to your class path, and done. This Discussion helped a lot.
[Batik not in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891250/batik-not-in-classpath)